# Trying to connect to my raspi with SSH, cant be pinged but can connect to the internet

Tags: raspbian, ssh, putty

I used to be able to use putty to connect to my pi via ssh. However, after having left it  on for a while and trying to connect a couple of days later, I was faced with the message "putty fatal error: no route to host". I tried pinging my laptops ip from my pi (and vice versa) and both times the output was "destination host unreachable". I have double checked the ip addresses used using ifconfig, checked all my putty settings and checked that ssh is enabled in raspi-config, but I still cannot get a connection working. using nmap from both my laptop and my pi (laptop running ubuntu 16.04) I ran nmap scanme.nmap.org and with my public ip, and my public ip returned a message saying:

"Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.13 seconds".

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a comment, but I can't post comments.

I would try  `ping 8.8.8.8` with the pi. If you still get nothing from your pi and your laptop's internet is not working either, then I would blame the router, and see what to do about that.

If you get nothing from your pi, but your laptop's internet is fine, then I would look at the logs with `sudo journalctl -b` and look through for anything internet related.  `dmesg` may also have useful output if something failed. `systemctl` will let you know the status of services and if they failed.

Have you installed a firewall or used iptable rules? If so, could you post those configurations as well as any interesting logs you find?